# layoutMarginsGuide producing unwanted leading and trailing margins

Tags: ios, swift, layout, autolayout

I'm creating constraints programmatically on my views. When I try to use the `layoutMarginsGuide` anchors, the top and bottom anchors work as expected, but the leading and trailing anchors create margins even if the insets are set at 0. What is creating these unwanted margins and how can I set them correctly?

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        view.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)


        let childView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        childView.backgroundColor = .systemIndigo
        childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(childView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            childView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
            childView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor),
            childView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
            childView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
        ])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike other views, the system manages the margins of a view controller's root view. By default, it enforces minimum left and right margins of either 16 or 20 points depending on the view width. The top and bottom margins are by default zero.

So if you want less margin of root view then system minimum. you have to make **false** to **viewRespectsSystemMinimumLayoutMargins**

```
viewRespectsSystemMinimumLayoutMargins = false
view.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
```

Comment: just try to print systemMinimumMargins by : print(systemMinimumLayoutmargins)

Answer (score 1):

So that the side contraints do not contain spaces and are completely glued to the sides, you have to remove the ***layoutMarginsGuide***, it would be like:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      childView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
      childView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor),
      childView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
      childView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
])
```